# Is it possible to adjust the brightness and contrast of an image simultaneously?

Tags: css

This might be explained better with pictures than words, so please run the code snippet and see what I mean. When using an image editor I can adjust both the brightness and contrast of an image in one go, resulting in a bright and clear image. But when using CSS, the brightness and contrast are changed sequentially in two steps, giving poor results.

Is there any way of adjusting both brightness and contrast in CSS at the same time? Using SVG or some JavaScript solution would also be okay if necessary.

```html
Original:<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/uZP6Tdf.jpg" height="250"><br>

GIMP - 63 brightness and contrast:<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ba8PHk2.png" height="250"><br>

CSS - 2 brightness, 2 contrast:<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/uZP6Tdf.jpg" height="250" style="filter: brightness(2) contrast(2);"><br>

CSS - 2 contrast, 2 brightness:<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/uZP6Tdf.jpg" height="250" style="filter: contrast(2) brightness(2);">
```

Comment: Pixabay is preventing most of your images from loading. Can you host them somewhere else? The one on Imgur works fine.

Comment: @mfluehr Oh is it? Works fine for me, even loading an incognito window with the cache disabled. But I'll replace the Pixabay links with Imgur now. May as well have it all on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend tweaking your CSS `filter` values until the appearance is more or less the same. I can't think of a more "scientific" way to do it, but I think the values I've used in the snippet below are very close to what you want.

```html
Original:<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/uZP6Tdf.jpg" height="250"><br>

GIMP - 63 brightness and contrast:<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ba8PHk2.png" height="250"><br>

CSS:<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/uZP6Tdf.jpg" height="250" style="filter: brightness(1.53) contrast(1.19);"><br>
```

Comment: This does indeed work rather well, though my particular use case for changing brightness/contrast in CSS is rather extreme and CSS affects the colours more than GIMP does (which doesn't saturate the colours at all when changing the brightness). Maybe this wouldn't work even if both brightness and contrast could be changed simultaneously.  :/